# Portion of image sensor used for 1080p video

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm trying to get the width and height of the sensor used when recording 1080p video for an image processing application using a raspi cam. I have noted the field of view changes from 1080p video to a 1080p still image, even though the resolution is the same. I believe, this is done due to a bit rate issue of h264 video.

All of these observations, make me confused as to how I can calculate the correct width and height in mm, when using 1080p video. In the [raspberry pi camera spec](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera.md), it says:

sensor resolution - 2592 x 1944 pixels

sensor dimensions - 3.76 x 2.74 mm

Will a straightforward linear interpolation be accurate? ex: (3.76 * 1920 / 2592). But, then it seems the image can be scaled as well, which happens in either the video or the still image format.

Note: I have calibrated the camera and have all intrinsic values in pixel units. My effort here is to convert all of these into mm.

Answer (score 0):

Just calibrate the camera for the mode you want to use.

The width and height of your sensor is given in the specs.
It also gives you a pixel size of 1.4µm x 1.4µm. If not given you could calculate it by dividing the sensor width by the image width. Same for height.

And it says that there is cropping in 1080p mode. This means that only a region of your sensor is used. Simply multiply your image width and height with the pixel size and you'll get the size of the sensor area that is used for 1080p.
To get the position of that area take a picture of the same scene in 1080p and in full resolution and compare them.

Not sure about the scaling. You did not provide sufficient information here.

You can either calibrate your camera in 1080p mode or you calibrate it in full resoultion and correct the pixel positions by some translation offset. Pixel size and physical position did not change through cropping...

Comment: The scaling is what I'm asking about. I do not have sufficient information I guess. Just an observation that confirms there's cropping. I have it calibrated in 1080p mode. I have the intrinsics, I'm just trying to get to the correct mm conversion from there.